# Conversão de date em um select

Tags: data, conversão

Estou com um probleminha referente ao comando que estou usando para criar um  relatório usando o `postgresql`, o comando é este:

```
select DTNASCIMENTO from FRONT.CONTATO where contato.dtnascimento::DATE = :DATA_INICIAL
```

Ele está retornando:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might
> need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 73

Se alguém puder dar uma luz eu agradeço...

Comment: Boa tarde, amigo! Para que o pessoal possa te ajudar melhor, por favor, de mais detalhes sobre o que você está tentando fazer e adicione a `tag` da linguagem que está utilizando.

Comment: Oi Boa tarde...eu estou tentando fazer uma query para extrair dadso de uma base de dadso, onde xiste uma coluna tipo "date" só que preciso dat um "get" para quando o usuário executar a query, seja perguntado qual data que deseja, fiz query mas quando vou informar a data para a filtragem  pelo comando: "select DTNASCIMENTO from FRONT.CONTATO where contato.dtnascimento::DATE = :DATA_INICIAL" dá mensagemd e que  a string  é int, eu acho que é por causa da mascara da coluna que esta como xx/xx/xxxx  <PLSQL> e obrigado pelo toque...